# Webscraper only looping twice through csv webscraper file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I created a webscraper and I wanted to pull the list of links from a csv file, everything works fine except that when pulling from the csv list and not a test list the program goes through one row and stops, with no errors. The end goal is to pull all the rows in a column from the links.csv and run those links through the webscraper and output to a second csv (latter portion works fine).

This is my first post and I'm a relatively new to python (and scripting at large) so any feedback is highly appreciated.

The website I'm pulling from for refference: https://www.mobilesentrix.com/oled-assembly-compatible-for-iphone-11-pro-aftermarket-plus-quality-boe-soft

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pandas import *

# Get list of links from CSV file
data = read_csv("links.csv")
```

This is the problem area ^^
When I read the csv to a list, it simply loops one time as seen-

```
# Loop through CSV list and extract price from html tag
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
for link in data:
    browser.get(link)
    price = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'regular-price')
    print("Price: " + price.text)
    df2 = DataFrame([[link, price.text]], columns=["Product", "Price"])
    df = df2.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

Here ^^ where it loops through the very first list item and goes to the lines below without issue.

```
# End webdriver and export dataframe
browser.close()
with open(r'write.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    df.to_csv(path_or_buf=csv_file)
print(df)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read_csv returns a dataframe, and you can't iterate through it in this manner. You should iterate through the column containing the links.
e.g.:

```
for link in data['links']:
```

or provide the column index.